# MassTransit trying to connect to RabbitMQ infinitely when it is down

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

When RabbitMQ is down, by default (I think) Masstransit trying to connect infinitely and getting "RabbitMQ Connect Failed: Broker unreachable: guest@localhost:5672/" error.

Masstransit started working as soon as RabbitMQ is up. Is there anyway we can set a limit on the number of retries? So Masstransit will stop retrying to connect RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit the time spent connecting to RabbitMQ, pass a `CancellationToken` to the `StartAsync` method.

```
using var source = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

await bus.StartAsync(source.Token);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, it seems to be resolving the issue. I've hostedservice in a separate library and calling from the console. Is it something we can pass cancellationtoken from the console instead of hard-coded on the library. `public class MTHostedService : IHostedService
    { } public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {}`

Comment: If you're using IHostedService, I'm not sure where the CancellationToken comes from, but you can certainly use it.

Comment: Do you think I should not have CancellationToken input parameter on StartAsync method as it is called by default if I use IHostedService? OR is there any other way i can call StartAsync method when I use IHostedService?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you have an IHostedService, ASP.NET Core will call that StartAsync method with a cancellation token. Pass that cancellation token to MassTransit's StartAsync method.

Comment: My StartAsync method has input parameter cancellationToken and it is not used, instead source.Token used.` public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        { using var source = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
await bus.StartAsync(source.Token);  } `.  I understand that we can create a linked token source like ` using var linkedTokenSource =CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, source.Token); await bus.StartAsync(linkedTokenSource.Token);`. I hope this is how it should work.